# jquery Datatables repeat header each X rows

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

What is the best method to repeat the "header" of a jquery datatable each X rows?

Without affecting later when ordering the rows?

I have achieved, completely eliminating the ordering of the table, with:

```
    $('#data-table').DataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "bSort": false
    });
```

But I would like a better solution ... to be able to sort by columns when clicking

Thank you very much!

Comment: You mean, header/row, header/row?

Comment: Why are you repeating the header? Have you thought about using a fixed header instead? Probably better UI: https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/ Also, as you have found out, adding the header row as a data row will mess up ordering, filtering, paging, etc because now the table will think these extra headers are data. You would have to hack a bunch of things to get it to "work"

Comment: I need to repeat header, because each row contains a lot of columns, and the height of each row is big because contains an image in the first column. It is almost impossible to interpret so much data without repeating the header.

Comment: @MiguelPérezMartínez I would use the fixed header if I was you. Check out a demo here: https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/simple.html (set the table length to 100 and scroll down)